# What is the URL for Google call/voice?

Tags: url, google-voice

I found a URL for Google Tasks:

- https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig

Is there something similar for Google call/voice? On my Gmail page I can click on the arrow on the Google call window to make it pop out (new window). The URL then points to:

- https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=btop&ver=1s4dmo0mhdqld

I cannot bookmark this link though, and if I paste it into the address bar I get a blank page.

I have already tried the following links:

- http://mail.google.com/call/ig
- http://mail.google.com/voice/ig

Comment: So you want the Call pane where you enter numbers just on its own page without the rest of the site?

Answer (score -2):

https://www.google.com/voice/

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I tried this but when I type in a contacts name and click on call, nothing happens, why is that?

Comment: TBH, I do not know.  I just found the link you asked for.  Sorry. :(